# Transaction reverted but not refunded

Tags: transactions

My transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd4f9905b14e26ee96b243f47e734e1b7880dc2a23f8f847dae786fca0f3f9888
has failed and was marked as reverted 15 hours ago.

Though i don't think my ETH wallet has been refunded yet.

Do you think this can take more than 1 day ?

Thanks

Comment: The refund is instant. My guess is that your wallet is not synchronized yet

Comment: Was it ever fully refunded afterall?
I am now facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Your transfer of 0.3 Eth was never made. It should still be in your wallet.

However, transaction fees are never refunded, even when a transaction reverts. You have to pay the miner to process your failed transaction.